# Validate JSON Schema with another JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate JSON Schema using another JSON Schema.

Example of JSON Schema to validate: https://jsonschema.net/home

Reference of Validation schema to validate above schema: https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/blob/master/lib/refs/json-schema-draft-07.json

I have a requirement where `property` can only be of primitive type i.e `string, number, integer, boolean`.
Since the root of JSON schema should have `type` as `object` and all the `properties` inside it will have `type` as primitive type, I am not sure how should I define `type` definition that validates the `type` at root level as `object` while `type` inside `properties` as primitive type.

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "$id": "http://example.com/example.json",
    "type": "object",
    "title": "The root schema",
    "description": "The root schema comprises the entire JSON document.",
    "default": {},
    "examples": [
        {
            "name": "A green door"
        }
    ],
    "required": [
        "name"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "$id": "#/properties/name",
            "type": "string",
            "title": "The name schema",
            "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
            "default": "",
            "examples": [
                "A green door"
            ]
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": true
}
```

Validation JSON that validates the `type`:

```
  definitions: {
    simpleTypes: {
      enum: ['array', 'boolean', 'integer', 'null', 'number', 'object', 'string'],
    }
  },
  properties: {
  type: {
      anyOf: [
        { $ref: '#/definitions/simpleTypes' },
      ],
    },
  }
```

From the above `simpleTypes -> enum` if I remove `object`, my JSON becomes invalid.

Any way I can define `enum` for root `type` as different from `type` present inside `properties`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by making a copy of the draft-07 schema and give it a unique `$id`.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/my-custom-draft-07-schema",
  "definitions": {
    ...original-definitions...
  },
  ...original-schema...
}
```

Since you want different constraints for schemas in different places, you'll need to refactor the schema to a definition so it can be referenced and extended for different situations. Don't forget to change all the recursive references (`{ "$ref": "#" }`) to point to the definition you created (`{ "$ref": "#/definitions/schema" }`).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/my-custom-draft-07-schema",
  "alllOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/schema" }],
  "definitions": {
    ...original-definitions-with-modified-$refs...
   "schema": {
      ...original-schema-with-modified-$refs...
    }
  }
}
```

Next you'll need to add another definition specific to property schemas and change the $refs for property schemas to use the definition that was created (`{ "$ref": "#/definitions/property-schema" }`). Don't forget to change `patternProperties` and `additionalProperties` as well as `properties`. Other keywords, such as `anyOf` should continue to reference the generic schema (`{ "$ref": "#/definitions/schema" }`).

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/my-custom-draft-07-schema",
  "alllOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/schema" }],
  "definitions": {
    ...original-definitions-with-modified-$refs...
    "schema": {
      ...original-schema-with-modified-$refs...
    },
    "property-schema": {
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/schema" }]
    }
  }
}
```

At this point, the schema has just been refactored. None of the behavior has changed except that you now have a place to put your custom constraints so they will only apply where you want them to. It should be relatively straightforward to add your constraints from here.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/my-custom-draft-07-schema",
  "alllOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/schema" }],
  ...add-root-schema-constraints-here...
  "definitions": {
    ...original-definitions-with-modified-$refs...
    "schema": {
      ...original-schema-with-modified-$refs...
      ...add-global-constraints-here...
    },
    "property-schema": {
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/schema" }]
      ...add-property-schema-constraints-here...
    }
  }
}
```